# How to get input data from mat-expansion panel-body?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to get the input data of the form. The whole page refreshes when I use the 'onSubmit' function and if I use the 'click' function the data will appear empty. I know the form is causing the problem, but I need the data from the form-fields.

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel [togglePosition]="'before'">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-icon [svgIcon]="'heroicons_outline:inbox-in'"></mat-icon>
      <mat-panel-title>Invite user</mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div class="ExpansionPanelBody pointerOn">
      <form class="mt-8" [formGroup]="inviteForm">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Message</mat-label>
          <input [formControlName]="'message'" matInput type="text" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
          <input
            [formControlName]="'email'"
            matInput
            type="email"
            maxlength="30"
          />
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
      <mat-action-row>
        <button
          (click)="sendInvite()"
          type="submit"
          mat-button
          color="primary"
        >
          Send invite
        </button>
      </mat-action-row>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

.ts file:

```
  this.inviteForm = new FormGroup({
      message: new FormControl(''),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    });

  sendInvite(): void {
    console.log(this.inviteForm.value);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your send button, which is outside of your form, so Angular cannot catch the submit event (that's why your try with `ngSubmit` doesn't work).

Also, verify if you don't forget to import the `ReactiveFormModule` inside your module.

If it's impossible to put it inside, just replace your button type by `"button"` to prevent the page refresh.

Comment: I put the button inside the form. Now I first have the form, then I have the fields and also the mat-action-row with the button inside of it. I changed the button type, but still no value when I call:  console.log(this.inviteForm.value);

Comment: If you put the button inside the form, then you can left the submit type for your button, and use (ngSubmit)="sendInvite()" in your form

Comment: Yeah, tried this many times. But the page keeps on refreshing

Comment: " tried this many times" -> With the button inside the form AND the `<form [formGroup]="...." (ngSubmit)="..." ` ?
Verify if you don't forget to import the `ReactiveFormModule` inside your module too ! :)

Comment: Yes, everything was included in the form, reactiveFormModule is also imported and still no value showing

Comment: Could you try to replace `[formControlName]="'message'"` by `formControlName="message"` (same for email) please ? If the problem persit, please, provide a stackblitz or codesandbox :)

Comment: I just runned the whole application from start and it is fixed now. I think it got bugged or something else. I don't understand what was causing the problem. Thanks for helping though!